# Removing a useless commit with rebase gives error

Tags: git

I made a commit to change one line of code, then I commited it ("Changed Project Name"). A few minutes later I realized that my change was wrong. so I changed it again, and commited one more time ("Corrected Project Name").

ow I have a useless commit, and I would like to remove it from the history. So I did this:

```
git rebase HEAD~6
```

and I removed the commit "Changed Project Name". But when I save the rebase file, I get this message:

```
error: could not apply 6df1da5... Corrected Project Name

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 6df1da5... Corrected Project Name
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By removing the commit with `git rebase -i`, you told git to discard the changes from that commit.

However, your next commit *builds on these changes* (because it changes the same line). Thus removing the earlier commit leads to a merge conflict. That is what git is telling you with the error message.

Of course, you don't want to discard the changes from the bad commit - you have already reverted it anyway. You just want to make it disappear from the history. To do that, you need to *squash* the two commits, i.e. combine them into one commit.

To do this:

- abort the running rebase (`git rebase --abort`)
- run `git rebase HEAD~6` again
- instead of deleting the bad commit, squash it ("s")

Now git will combine the two commits into one commit, and it will look as if you had directly performed the correct change :-).

Comment: Alternatively, edit the file containing the project name and manually resolve the conflict, then `git add` it and `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: Excellent! Squash is exactly what I should have been using! Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your history seems to look like this:

```
* HEAD   Corrected Project Name
* HEAD~1 Changed Project Name
* HEAD~2 some other commit
* ...
```

If you only used HEAD to undo the changes of HEAD~1, you can just throw away both commits using `git reset --hard HEAD~2`. This results in:

```
* HEAD some other commit
* ...
```

If the last two commits introduced some important change and you only want to combine them, you can either use `git rebase -i` and interactively squash both commits, or use `git reset --soft HEAD~2; git commit`. Both will result in:

```
* HEAD   Combined commit
* HEAD~1 some other commit
* ...
```